# Send email when "ERROR" is found in JBoss server log

Tags: jboss, jboss-eap-7

I want to configure JBoss Server(EAP 7.1) such way, that if a particular "error code" or "error string" is found inside server log, an automatic email should be triggered to certain recipient.

I have never used such facility before in application server(used in CIT like Jenkins). Please let me know if anybody does such configuration.

Comment: A little old but this should get you going [Creating A Custom Logging Handler In JBOSS As 710 Final](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/CreatingACustomLoggingHandlerInJBOSSAs710Final) - not really worthy of an official "Answer".  Let me know if it works out for you - and seeing as how it's from 2012/2013 there may be a better way of doing it now.

Comment: Also, a newer post that uses log4j which makes the process way easier [wildfly 10 mail logger](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/276681)